# Do anybody wear solely rabbeinu tam tefillin

Tags: halacha, tefilin, rashi, communities, rabbeinu-tam

Many people follow the majority Halacha practice of wearing Rashi tefillin. Some people, especially but not exclusively Sephardim and Hasidism, also wear Rabbeinu Tam, which is seen as an act of piety. My question is, are there any communities or individuals which wear Rabbeinu Tam tefillin but not rashi, and if not why not?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86782/6592

Comment: Well no one wears complete Rabbeinu Tam since he held the parshiyos lay flat ...the orientation of parshios seemed not to be exclusive to RT ...