How could Tannaim argue about things which people would not forget?
I'm new to Mi Yodea, so I apologize if I'm using this incorrectly. Here is my question:
The משנה is the collection of Torah Shebe'al Peh, passed down from Matan Torah until today. There are, however, sometimes debates in the משנה which seem to be impossible, since they are about things quite common. Here are some examples:

Pesachim 10:2 - Beis Shammai and Beis Hillel argue about the order of Kiddush. If this was something done every week, how could they forget the proper order?
Berachos 6:1 - The Tanna Kamma says that vegetables receive a Borei Pri Ha'adamah, while Rebbi Yehuda says that leafy vegetables require a בורא מיני דשאים. Did they never have leafy greens that a debate could happen regarding something so common?

Now, perhaps these two are D'rabanan and were established when those mishnayos were made, but there are some examples which are even D'Oraisa!

Berachos 1:2 and 1:3 - I was told that these a D'oraisa. If there is such a large period between the deadline of R' Eliezer and R' Yehoshua, how could they forget when the deadline MiSinai was? Did most people recite Krias Shema in this small timeframe? The next Mishna discusses a machlokes regarding the proper position to recite Shema in, which surely there could have been no doubt about?
Pesachim 4:5 - The Machlokes between Rebbi Yehuda and Rebbi Meir is discussing a safeguard from Chazal. Though it could be said this machlokes was talking about what should be implemented rather than what the halacha is, Rebbi Yehuda brings a proof from the time of the Beis HaMikdash, meaning that this decree was in place then, so how could there be a portion of the community which forgot about the proper time to dispose of chametz?!
Succah 3:4 - The Lulav was taken every year, yet the Tannaim are arguing about how many of each to take? How could there be any doubt? Did Rebbi Akiva really do like Rebbi Yishmael (the amount today), yet disagreed about the minimum to fulfill the mitzvah?


Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86782/did-rabeinu-tam-wear-rashi-tefilin

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I highly recommend the book The Dynamics of Dispute, by Zvi Lampel. He talks about some of these cases, but the principles he explains there (the various ways in which machlokes developed and persisted) are applicable to all of them.

Thanks, shmosel and @mbloch.

@Meir Thank you for the recommendation, I may buy the book.
